# In asp.net core how to access Environment in a ControllerBase?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How do you access the Environment in a ControllerBase?

I have a ControllerBase like:

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class ControllerBase : Controller
    {
       private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

      public string CommonEMailHeader(string Event)
      {

            string AltMessage = "";

            if(_env != null)
            {
                if (_env.EnvironmentName == "Development")
                {
                    AltMessage = "Development<br />";
                }
            }

        string HTMLHeader = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>";
       ... lots more unrelated code ...

       return HTMLHeader;
      }


    }
}
```

The Function works when I call it from a Controller, but the '_env' is always null.

Comment: Do not tag both asp.net and asp.net-core. Also make sure you tag the correct version of asp.net-mvc/asp.net-core-mvc

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject it, if you are using it like that:

```
public abstract class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    protected ControllerBase(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }
```

Comment: Your example gives me this error:
error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'env' of 'ControllerBase.ControllerBase(IWebHostEnvironment)'
in my HomeController.

Comment: Is this asp.net core?

Comment: Yes. asp.net core. netcore 3

Comment: As `mxmissile` said,with dependency injection,an IWebHostEnvironment will be injected to your controller.Can you share your updated code with error CS7036?